# React Card Hover Effect with react spring not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-spring

I want to create a card hover effect in which the card translates according to the mouse position inside the card and the blob follows the mouse position inside the card

the blob

```
<div
          className={`absolute w-[500px] border-none  bottom-[50px] h-[1000px] z-[-1] back ${
            hovered ? "opacity-95" : "opacity-0"
          } `}
          style={{
            transform: `translateX(${translateX}px) translateY(${
              2 * translateY
            }px)`,
            background: backgroundColor,
            borderRadius: "100%",
            mixBlendMode: "soft-light",
            left: left,
            filter: "blur(180px)",
            willChange: "transform",
            transition: "transform 0.2s cubic-bezier",
          }}
        ></div>
```

full implementation

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useSpring, animated } from "@react-spring/web";

export type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  backgroundColor: string;
  direction: string;
  left: string;
};

const calc = (x: number, y: number): [number, number, number] => [
  -(y - window.innerHeight / 2) / 360,
  (x - window.innerWidth / 2) / 240,
  1.02,
];

const trans = (x: number, y: number, s: number): string =>
  `perspective(900px) rotateX(${-x}deg) rotateY(${-y}deg)`;

const HoverCard: React.FC<Props> = ({
  children,
  backgroundColor,
  direction,
  left,
}) => {
  const [hovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);
  const [springProps, set] = useSpring(() => ({
    xys: [0, 0, 1],
    config: { mass: 5, tension: 6000, friction: 1000 },
  }));

  const [cursorCoords, setCursorCoords] = useState({ x: 0, y: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    const handleMousePosition = (event: MouseEvent) => {
      const { clientX: x, clientY: y } = event;
      setCursorCoords({ x, y });
    };

    window.addEventListener("mousemove", handleMousePosition);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("mousemove", handleMousePosition);
    };
  }, []);

  const calcTranslate = (
    coordinate: number,
    containerSize: number,
    itemSize: number
  ) => (coordinate / containerSize) * (containerSize - itemSize);

  const translateX =
    typeof window !== "undefined"
      ? calcTranslate(cursorCoords.x, window.innerWidth, 600)
      : 0;
  const translateY =
    typeof window !== "undefined"
      ? calcTranslate(cursorCoords.y, window.innerHeight, 500)
      : 0;

  const handleMouseMove = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) => {
    const { clientX: x, clientY: y } = event;
    set({ xys: calc(x, y) });
    setIsHovered(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    set({ xys: [0, 0, 1] });
    setIsHovered(false);
  };

  return (
    <animated.div
      className="  overflow-hidden  mb-3 md:mb-8 rounded-xl"
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
      style={{ transform: springProps.xys.to(trans) }}
    >
      <div
        className={`z-[1] relative bg-white dark:bg-[#161b22] h-full border-[#30363d] border-[0.5px] rounded-xl shadow-xl md:flex  ${direction} justify-between`}
      >
        {children}
//this is the blob        
<div
          className={`absolute w-[500px] border-none  bottom-[50px] h-[1000px] z-[-1] back ${
            hovered ? "opacity-95" : "opacity-0"
          } `}
          style={{
            transform: `translateX(${translateX}px) translateY(${
              2 * translateY
            }px)`,
            background: backgroundColor,
            borderRadius: "100%",
            mixBlendMode: "soft-light",
            left: left,
            filter: "blur(180px)",
            willChange: "transform",
            transition: "transform 0.2s cubic-bezier",
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </animated.div>
  );
};

export default HoverCard;
```

In my case the blob is way off the actual mouse position in the card and the card doesn't translate properly

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/adoring-torvalds-f3l5rv?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltx5sit100072a699snf968d%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltx5sisz00022a69lp2rp5zo%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltx5sit000042a69jqm7v3ts%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltx5sit100062a69kydhekmw%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B53.18260203104042%252C46.81739796895958%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522cltx5sisz00022a69lp2rp5zo%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltx5sisz00022a69lp2rp5zo%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522cltx5sit100062a69kydhekmw%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltx5sit000052a69exjg3pft%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltx5sit100062a69kydhekmw%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltx5sit000052a69exjg3pft%2522%257D%252C%2522cltx5sit000042a69jqm7v3ts%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltx5sit000042a69jqm7v3ts%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltx5sit000032a69vip6zghb%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltx5sit000032a69vip6zghb%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

I am expecting to get an effect in which the card will smoothly translate with the mouse position and i can see a blur blob in the background following the cursor inside the card

Any help is much appreciated , Thank you